# pybind11: add callback function for "module constructor"

Tags: python, cpython, pybind11

The [pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#module-destructors) has a section about "module destructors". How do you implement "module constructors" with pybind11?

Let's say I want to execute a C++ function when my module is imported in Python. Normally, if this was a Python module, I would just add the command with function call into the top-level scope in `module.py`. This is the most basic thing you can do in a Python module - execute a command. But pybind11's [first steps](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#creating-bindings-for-a-simple-function) start with adding a *function definition*. How do I add a *command* to the pybind11 module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the contents of the function defined with [the `PYBIND11_MODULE` macro](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#c.PYBIND11_MODULE) is for. It's a regular function, you can do whatever setup you need in there; sure, calls on `m` (like `m.def`) are what you commonly see, but you can do anything you like in it to set up your module.